# Occupy space-between center in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make a the elements of a div, like the one from [Angular](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment) (space-between center), occupy the entire space but with "pure" css?

My approach was the following: [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6bayk9d9/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="nested-fields pull-left">
      <div class="fields">
        <textarea>
            bla bla bla
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nested-fields">
      <div class="fields">
        <textarea>
            bla bla bla
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nested-fields pull-right">
      <div class="fields">
        <textarea>
            bla bla bla
        </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.nested-fields {
  display: inline-block;
}

.boxes {
  text-align:center;
}

.pull-left {
    float: left !important;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

however once I add another nested-field, it doesn't look the way I want. That is, I want it to behave exactly the same way as the Angular space-between center child alignment.

The final purpose is to add dynamic fields where the div should readjust his child alignments.

Any tips on how can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: You need to include real code in question when linking to jsfiddle. Not just change normal text into code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the problems solved by [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), set the container `display:flex` and `justify-content` to `space-between`, and no need for all other markup as you can see in this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/1cjz8g6r/)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea>bla bla bla</textarea>
  <textarea>bla bla bla</textarea>
  <textarea>bla bla bla</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped, but next time you ask a question remember that you need to meet S.O MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve